# Carry POST data to another page

Tags: php, forms, paypal, http-post

I have a php form that at the moment posts the data to a Paypal cart, but I want to post the data to a new php page almost like a confirmation page which shows the options and selections you selected to and from that point for you to be able to send on to Paypal?

Is this possible?

Comment: several keys on your keyboard appear to work intermittently =)

Comment: I am extremely sorry for the typos, I have so many windows open, please accept my apologies =)

Answer (score 2):

Someone new to session or post may find this example helpful. complete example of what you want. how to Store and view post array into a session named POSTDATA.post or anyother variables are accessible to a same session, from any page if its stored in a session variable.

**form.php**

```
<?php
//PHP content of form.php file
session_start();
if ($_POST)
{
    $_SESSION['POSTDATA']=$_POST;
}
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <form action="form.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="hello"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form>
  <!--<a href="anotherpage.php">link to some another page for testing</a>-->
</body>
</html>
```

**anotherpage.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "This is some another page somewhere inside.ANOTHER PAGE SAYS";
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION['POSTDATA']);
echo '<pre>';
echo "INPUT BOX VALUE ".$_SESSION['POSTDATA']['hello'].'<br/>';
echo "SUBMIT BUTTON VALUE ".$_SESSION['POSTDATA']['submit'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to store the post data in $_session['post'] = $_POST to persist the storage and get the posted data on the new page with $_session['post']['field']

Comment: Do you have an example of this, I am not too familiar with sessions I am very new to it. I do apologise im not being ignorant or lazy as I have only started learning PhP this week...

Comment: Yes that is php Sessions. It is a good way to store values for use with different pages on the same domain.

Comment: Ok so I am able to submit a form and for the submitted information to be posted and shown on another page so say post.php contains the form and the data, submit it to show the submiteed data on say results.php?

Comment: How is the the data post to paypal today? Is it directly posted to there or do you use curl to the postdata there?

often you are about to verify the userdata before that is posted to for example paypal. If you are doing it this way you are able to save the post data in session.

Comment: it would be best to answer your question if you vist the website im working to do this.

http://cherished-4ever.co.uk/order.php

I am struggling to change the uploaded filename to a timestamp, I got this working before but some how deleted the code and now it keeps saying its an invalid file...

Comment: If you could put the code up here it would be alot easier to determine what it is that is going wrong. Do you keep the extension of the filename before you change it to timestamp?

For example
$uploaddir = '/uploadedfiles/';
$filename = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key]); 
$filenameext = $filename[count($filename)-1];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $upload_dir.time().$filenameext);

Comment: <?php 
 $target = "upload/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target )) 
 {
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
 } 
 else {
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
 }
 ?>

Comment: This code is for my file upload where im struggling to get the timestamp to work, I can get it to show after the extension but it obviously makes the file no longer readable...

Comment: I figured it out, just use $_REQUEST and let the handler.php file display the selected form information. I need to know how to send this over to PayPal now